# Parse a JSON with an empty string field

Tags: json, go, encoding-json-go

I need to parse a JSON into Go struct. Following is the struct

```
type Replacement struct {
Find        string `json:"find"`
ReplaceWith string `json:"replaceWith"`
}
```

Following is an example json:

```
{
"find":"TestValue",
"replaceWith":""
}
```

The input json can have empty values for some field. Go's `encoding/json` library by default takes `nil` value for any empty string provided in JSON.
I've a downstream service, which finds and replaces the `replaceWith` values in configurations. This is causing issues with my downstream service as it doesn't accept `nil` for the `replaceWith` parameter. I have a workaround where I'm replacing `nil` values by `"''"` but this can cause an issue where some value is replaced with `''`. Is there a way for json to *not* parse empty string as nil and just `""`

Here is a link to the code: https://play.golang.org/p/SprPz7mnWR6

Comment: No, `encoding/json` does not use `nil` for empty values. Show your code.

Comment: @BurakSerdar updated the question with the code.

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you want. 'ReplaceWith' is set to the empty string

Comment: @htyagi in your posted example ReplaceWith is not `nil` but an empty string - exactly what you asked for - see here: https://play.golang.org/p/MZWtUDNPXLg

Comment: Your code must be _in the question_. Links go stale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go string type cannot hold `nil` value which is zero value for pointers, interfaces, maps, slices, channels and function types, representing an uninitialized value.

When unmarshalling JSON data to struct as you do in your example `ReplaceWith` field will indeed be an empty string (`""`) - which is exactly what you are asking for.

```
type Replacement struct {
    Find        string `json:"find"`
    ReplaceWith string `json:"replaceWith"`
}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`
    {
           "find":"TestValue",
           "replaceWith":""
    }`)
    var marshaledData Replacement
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &marshaledData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    if marshaledData.ReplaceWith == "" {
        fmt.Println("ReplaceWith equals to an empty string")
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I didn't realise that. blami's comment above made it more clear to me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pointer in string and if the value is missing in JSON then it would be nil. I have done the same in past but currently I don't have code with me.